# ursina engine error but still running, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ursina

so this is the code:

```
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()

player = Entity(model='cube', color=color.orange, scale_y=2)


def update():   # update gets automatically called.
    player.x += held_keys['d'] * .1
    player.x -= held_keys['a'] * .1
    player.y += held_keys['w'] * .1
    player.y -= held_keys['s'] * .1


app.run()
```

and it's giving me this error:

```
E:\Python\ursina\venv\Scripts\python.exe E:/Python/ursina/main.py
package_folder: E:\Python\ursina\venv\lib\site-packages\ursina
asset_folder: E:\Python\ursina
blender_paths:
{}
screen resolution: (1366, 768)
Known pipe types:
wglGraphicsPipe
(3 aux display modules not yet loaded.)
size; LVector2f(1092, 614)
```

**NOTE**: the code runs perfectly fine but I'm just a little cofused :)
thanks for answering my stupid question

Comment: Is this actually an error? Looks like debug output to me

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the output message

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error, it is just a debug output as @ForceBru said, and that's why it's running perfectly. As far as I know, you can't remove or avoid it easily.

However, there is no real reason to remove it even if you do find a solution, as it won't appear in a game.

I'll still break it down for you (What I think they mean):

`package_folder: E:\Python\ursina\venv\lib\site-packages\ursina` is just the path to Ursina on your PC.

`asset_folder: E:\Python\ursina` is the path to all the loaded Assets.

`blender_paths: {}` : The blender (3D engine) objects

`screen resolution: (1366, 768)`: Screen resolution..

This: `wglGraphicsPipe (3 aux display modules not yet loaded.) size; LVector2f(1092, 614)` is console output from the Panda3D module.